# Can I use a Yongnuo 622C trigger and sync cable to get high-speed sync with my Godox SK400 strobe?

Tags: yongnuo, wireless-triggers, godox

I have a Godox strobe, the SK400 (and an SK300) and a Yongnuo YN-622C trigger. If I use a Yongnuo  LS-PC635 (PC to 3.5mm) sync cable between the receiver and the strobe, can I  shoot in high speed sync with a shutter speed above 1/250s?

On the strobe's specifications it says it supports up to 1/2000s.
I now use the Godox FT16 trigger, I can't go faster than 1/250s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you possibly can use a faster-than 1/250s shutter speed. But not with HSS.

You *might* be able to use a higher shutter speed than your camera body's maximum sync speed, if you use the YN-622C's "supersync" feature and if your strobe's duration pattern works with supersync.  But this is not high-speed sync. This is where the sync timing is delayed until the "flatter" tail of the pulse, for more even illumination as the shutter gap sweeps across the sensor. But it relies heavily on exact timing and strobe pulse duration, and will typically only work with the strobe on full power, and only with certain strobes.

You definitely have to use the PC/3.5mm sync cable to do this, as supersync only works with the YN-622's PC output. And you may have to mess with the YN-622's Fn 01 to adjust the timing.  To use it, on the 622 triggers, set HSS.

See also: Clive Bolton's [TOYUG](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B77OmmGIg0gMMzZFaDVlZ1VNTE0/view) (the Other YN-622C User Guide).

> On the strobe's specifications it says it supports up to 1/2000s.

No. What it says on the specifications is that the "Flash Duration" is 1/2000s-1/800s. This is how long the flash pulse lasts. It's 1/2000s at the lowest power setting (1/16), and 1/800s at the highest power setting (full power). This is why supersync *might* work.  If you have the flash at full power, the pulse lasts 1/800s.  And if your shutter speed is 1/1000 or faster, you may be able to use the tail of the pulse for the entire exposure.

Comment: when the cable comes to me I will rehearse and I will be able to tell you. thanks in the meantime.

Answer (score 2):

i confirm it. Cable sync Yongnuo YN-622C trigger with godox sk400/300 can shot at 1/2000 with in super sync mode.

that's just a quick try with 1/2000 3.5 and ss
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Those monolights are not capable of HSS (or TTL or any other 'smarter' flash feature), it is a manual only flash. You will have to upgrade those lights to get that functionality. It appears that you would need the QT or Wistro series to get the HSS functionality.

The fact that the lights can have a duration as low 1/2000s has nothing to do with the sync speed or your shutter speed.  For instance, if you wanted to shoot water droplets, you can use a 5s shutter speed in a dark room and set your lights to fire at 1/2000s to freeze the action. These are independent settings.

Even if they did support HSS, the 622 triger would not be compatible with them except as a 'dumb' trigger.