# HSS and TTL not working with Fuji X-Pro2 and Godox system

Tags: fujifilm, ttl, strobes, godox, high-speed-sync

I own a Fuji X-Pro2 camera. I recently bought a Godox XPro-F trigger and a Godox SK400ii strobe to try out some flash portrait photography.

I can easily get everything working at normal shutter speeds and in manual mode on the flash/trigger, however when I switch over to TTL mode on the trigger, things aren't working how I'd expect. I'm not sure how much of the issue is ignorance or user error at this point... Here are the problems I'm running into right now:

1. In TTL mode on the trigger, adjusting the exposure doesn't change the output at all. When I set it to TTL mode, the strobe power goes to 0 and the strobe doesn't fire. It doesn't matter what settings I change on the trigger or camera at this point, the strobe does nothing. I can adjust the power on the strobe, but that defeats the point of TTL, right?
2. In both TTL and M mode, when I set up the camera and trigger to use HSS, everything works great at > 1/250 of a second. When I move the shutter speed past 1/250, the strobe stops firing. It fires again when I change the sync mode on the camera to front or rear sync instead of FP, but stops when I'm back on FP.

Any ideas? I've gone through a bunch of forums and youtube videos at this point, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong... Thanks for the help!

Comment: Re: 1. How bright is the scene without the strobe? Does the camera think no additional light is needed?

Comment: Related: [Can I use a Yongnuo 622C trigger and sync cable to get high-speed sync with my Godox SK400 strobe?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/96334/can-i-use-a-yongnuo-622c-trigger-and-sync-cable-to-get-high-speed-sync-with-my-g)

Answer (score 2):

The SK400II doesn't suport TTL or HSS. In a monolight, you have to upgrade to something like the QT series, or one of the AD battery powered lights.

The trigger supports all the Godox 2.4GHz lights, so it has controls for TTL and HSS. Not all lights support these features though.